# sending mail using post method

Tags: php, email, post

I want to send mail to users but when i click on submit button, the email isn't sent and I get an error that says request was not sent. here is my code,

```
<?php
include('submit.php');

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    extract($_POST); 
    $to = "chintan.suthar777@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Email template";
    $message =  file_get_contents('index.php');              
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: chintan.suthar777@gmail.com";
    $mail_sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  

    if($mail_sent)
        echo "<script>alert('Thank you. we will get back to you');
           window.location='index.php';exit();</script>";
    else
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry.Request not send');
           window.location='index.php';exit();</script>";

    }
?>
```

my HTML code is below:

```
<form name="news_data" action="email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>News </h3></td><td><input type="text" readonly value="1" name="sec_1_new[]" id="sec_1_new_1"  /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
             <td>Title of news :</td>
             <td><input type="text"  name="sec_1_title_news[]" id="sec_1_title_news_1" /><br /><br /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
             <td>Description: </td>
             <td><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="sec_1_desc[]" id="sec_1_desc_1" ></textarea><br /><br /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
             <td>Title of Link :</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="sec_1_newslink[]" id="sec_1_newslink_1"  /><br /><br /></td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>URL of News:</td>
            <td><a href="#"><input type="text" name="sec_1_news_url[]" id="sec_1_news_1_url" /><br /><br /></a></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
              <td>News image:</td>
              <td><input type="file" name="sec_1_news_img[][]" id="sec_1_news_1_image" ><br /><br /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td align="right"><input class="add" type="button" value="Add" id="sec_1_news_1_add" onClick="add_new(this.id)" /></td>

         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Add a form HTML as well

Comment: check if your server supports mail sending functionality.

Comment: edited with html code

Answer (score 0):

Check if you message start with '.', because that messages are removed, for that use `str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $text);` 
Check if your $message bigger than 70 character add `$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");`

Comment: still getting same error.

Comment: Can you write all error ?

Comment: not like error but like this:
echo "<script>alert('Sorry.Request not send');
           window.location='index.php';exit();</script>";

Comment: an alert of "sorry. request not send"

Comment: I think this is your host problem, connect with support your hosting